# How to send data to a specific client using IP addresses or another method in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, server

I have a PHP server and in order for the user to have updated information on their client app. I have set an interval that sends Ajax requests to the server and updates the client.

However, I like the idea of this alternative architecture more; When there's a change to the database, the server finds the related users to that change and it has their IP addresses already. Could the server send the updated information to those specific clients?

Or in other words, could the client app be listening, and whenever the server decides it will send the information to it? Would this be possible on the web?

**EDIT:** Currently the server works as a REST API. Would not using the current architecture of interval requests stop the API from functioning?

Comment: It is possible, are the users logged in on the website or something? You could save some information in a session and query data from your database depending on what data is in the session

Comment: Try it using sockets!

Comment: Yea they are logged in using sessions in the DB. The sessions store user_id, username and the IP address. What should I do with this information

Comment: You can do anything you want, it depends on what you want to show them. You can save easly other data in the database and add there the column user_id to it so that data is connected to that user